# how to process only each "x" message?

Tags: wso2-esb

I have a system A (generating messages each 1 second) linked over WSO2 EI with a system B (REST API).
The system B does not need so much data and it would be enough to send only each 60th message (so to speak kind of sampling).

could you please, tell me how to send out only each "x" message in the WSO2 EI?
Either time based (e.g every 60 sec) or count based (each 100th message)?

thx a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but maybe the following will work for you.

1. Store a counter value somewhere (e.g. database)
2. When system A generates a message, read that value from store
   (database)
3. Increase that value and store it (e.g. databse)
4. Check if counter modulo 60 = 0
5. If so, send to system B otherwise do nothing

This should be possible using db mediator, script mediator and filter mediator.

Hope that helps.